# sort by multiple columns using awk

Tags: linux, sorting, unix, awk

I have the following `sort` code:

```
sort -t, -k18,18n -k21,21nr
```

which sort a file with `,` delimiter, first ascending by column `$18`, then descending by column `$21`.

I am looking for an equivalent of this command using `awk`

Please advice

Comment: Why can't you use sort, and why do you want to use awk for this?

Comment: @melpomene the files I have contain millions of records, and sort command is time consuming, so I am looking for a time efficient way to get the same result.

Comment: It's unlikely you're going to find something faster than `sort`.

Comment: @melpomene solved by answered code, and it is much more faster. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved using the following code:

```
$ awk -F, 'a[$18]<$21{a[$18]=$21;b[$18]=$0}END{for(l in b){print b[l]}}'
```

Comment: If this works for you that's great, but it has no relationship to the question you asked.

Comment: @mpez0 It do the same work, giving the maximum value of $21 for each $18, without duplication.

Comment: picking the max, or a set of max values, is very different from sorting the entire list. I'm glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I suggest that write a script such as python. 
like this:
    import csv
    data = csv.reader("filename")
    s = sorted(s, key = lambda x: (x[18], x[21]))
    print s